# Other than the default ClassLoader in Mono?

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android

I am having a hell of a time implementing the [IParcelable](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=T:Android.OS.IParcelable) interface with Mono for android. My latest problem is reading the values that I have written to a Parcel. Standard types such as Strings, Integers etc. are no problem. I can write and read values perfectly. But, when I try to read values out a list of my own defined class `MyType`

```
List<MyType> MyTypes;
...
parcel.ReadList(MyTypes, null);
```

I get the following error

```
Android.OS.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: cinterface.MyType
```

I guess this is because of the default classloader, which does not know about the type of items in the list. The documentation states that `null` value used as the second parameter of [ReadList](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=M:Android.OS.Parcel.ReadList) uses the default classloader. I would like to use a custom classloader pointing to my class `cinterface.MyType`, but I have no idea how I could do this. Any help is highly appreciated.

Similar posts that I have gone through (but no luck) are here:

1. [android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865688/android-os-badparcelableexception-classnotfoundexception-when-unmarshalling-ex)
2. [BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: (empty classname)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10552062/badparcelableexception-classnotfoundexception-when-unmarshalling-empty-classn)
3. [BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393751/badparcelableexception-classnotfoundexception-when-unmarshalling)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Xamarins official sample here: https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ExportAttribute/ExportAttributeTest/MainActivity.cs It shows how to implement `IParcelable`.