# Class not found when unmarshalling when passing Parcelable through Messenger to remote service

Tags: android

I have a Parcelable object which I use to pass it from Activity to remote service. When I pass it using **AIDL** interface, everything sounds fine.

Recently, I try to pass it through **Messenger** from Activity.

```
// TEST TEST TEST!
StockInfo stockInfo0 = new StockInfo(Code.newInstance("code0"), Symbol.newInstance("symbol0"));
StockInfo stockInfo1 = new StockInfo(Code.newInstance("code1"), Symbol.newInstance("symbol1"));
StockInfo stockInfo2 = new StockInfo(Code.newInstance("code2"), Symbol.newInstance("symbol2"));
List<StockInfo> stockInfos = new ArrayList<StockInfo>();
stockInfos.add(stockInfo0);
stockInfos.add(stockInfo1);
stockInfos.add(stockInfo2);
StockInfosEx stockInfosEx = new StockInfosEx(stockInfos, "abc");
msg.obj = stockInfosEx;

try {
    mService.send(msg);
} catch (RemoteException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'm getting the following exception in remote service.

> 02-21 22:55:16.546: E/Parcel(8365): Class not found when
>   unmarshalling: com.example.testonmessenger.StockInfosEx, e:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.example.testonmessenger.StockInfosEx

I was wondering, what can get wrong in between? Here is my Parcelable object.

```
public class StockInfosEx implements Parcelable {
    public final List<StockInfo> stockInfos;
    public final String searchedString;

    public StockInfosEx(List<StockInfo> stockInfos, String searchedString) {
        this.stockInfos = stockInfos;
        this.searchedString = searchedString;
    }

    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Handling Parcelable nicely.

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<StockInfosEx> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<StockInfosEx>() {
        public StockInfosEx createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new StockInfosEx(in);
        }

        public StockInfosEx[] newArray(int size) {
            return new StockInfosEx[size];
        }
    };

    private StockInfosEx(Parcel in) {
        stockInfos = new ArrayList<StockInfo>();
        in.readTypedList(stockInfos, StockInfo.CREATOR);
        searchedString = in.readString();
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeTypedList(stockInfos);
        parcel.writeString(searchedString);
    }

    // Handling Parcelable nicely.    
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////        
}
```

To get complete source code, kindly download from https://www.dropbox.com/s/n69yuhddpb8vedz/testonmessenger.zip

Comment: is StockInfo parcelable ?

Comment: yes. i posted the complete source code just in case you are interested. what make me doubt is the whole parcelable is workable under AIDL, but not Messenger.

Comment: also, post complete stacktrace

Comment: That's the only stack trace from logcat. Believe me. It is only 1 line.

Comment: i don't believe you, sorry.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/setnxXL.png

Comment: you are filtering it somehow. there should at least be stuff like your app starting

Answer (score 23, accepted):

### Not Workable Approach (Because our Parcelable is custom, not part of Framework like Rect)

**Activity**

```
msg.obj = stockInfosEx;
```

**Remote Service**

```
StockInfosEx stockInfosEx = (StockInfosEx)msg.obj;
```

### Workable Approach

**Activity**

```
msg.getData().putParcelable("data", stockInfosEx);
```

**Remote Service**

```
msg.getData().setClassLoader(StockInfosEx.class.getClassLoader());
StockInfosEx stockInfosEx = (StockInfosEx)msg.getData().getParcelable("data");
```

---

Now, after I read back the documentation of msg.obj (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#obj) again, only I understand what it really mean by `Parcelable of a framework class`

> An arbitrary object to send to the recipient. When using Messenger to
>   send the message across processes this can only be non-null if it
>   contains a Parcelable of a framework class (not one implemented by the
>   application). For other data transfer use setData(Bundle).
>
> Note that Parcelable objects here are not supported prior to the FROYO
>   release.

Answer (score 6):

You're probably not using the right `ClassLoader`. You need to keep track of the `ClassLoader` that is marshalling the class in the first place, and use THAT `ClassLoader` to unmarshall it.

When unmarshalling, you're using current thread's ClassLoader, which is not your UIThread but Android system thread, and as such, has no info about your custom classes.

I used a static class that contained my `ClassLoader` to solve this (similar approaches can be used without having it to be static).

Something like:

```
ClassLoaderHelper.setClassLoader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
```

Then when unmarshalling:

```
public final void readFromParcel(final Parcel in) {
    id = in.readString();
    appInfo = in.readParcelable(ClassLoaderHelper.getClassLoader());
    ...
}
```

See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393751/badparcelableexception-classnotfoundexception-when-unmarshalling) for more detailed information (probably a duplicate btw).

Comment: Yup. I'm have double checked. Pretty sure correct classloader is being use during marshalling and unmarshalling. If not, the data structures is not usable for AIDL case.

Comment: I'm telling you because I've had this problem before and I too was sure the right ClassLoader was being used, and it was not. When unmarshalling, you're using Android's default ClassLoader which has no information about your custom classes. I used a static class that contained my ClassLoader to solve this. Did you read CommonsWare's answer btw?

Comment: But, my remote service is in different process than activity. How can they refer to a same class loader? I perform further testing. My remote service can explicitly construct `StockInfosEx`. So, it should know the definition of it. Just that I'm not sure why Parcel fail on that.

Comment: Perhaps you would like to help to test run on the complete source code, to see whether you can provide any valuable input? thanks ya!

Comment: OK. After reading the documentation and referring back your link, I can understand why my code doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: In my case I'm also passing objects between service and app. This doesn't matter as long as the class of the object is found on both sides.

Answer (score 3):

> I'm getting the following exception in remote service.

If you are truly getting this from the remote service, it is because the remote service app does not contain that class. If you are going to use custom `Parcelable` classes, both the client and the server must have the same class definition.

If, however, your stack trace feels like your `Parcelable` is being accessed from a core OS process, then you cannot pass `Parcelable` objects via `obj` reliably. I have only ever used `obj` on `Message` for in-process object passing, never for cross-process messages.

Comment: Yes. I just found out that I cannot pass **custom** `Parcelable` object via `obj`. I need to use `Bundle`.