# Starting new activity gives: Class not found when unmarshalling

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, parcelable

I'm facing a problem when passing a list of parcelable objects to the `intent` of one new `activity`.

Here's what I do:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, CurriculumCorsesActivity.class);
intent.setExtrasClassLoader(CurriculumCourseCard.class.getClassLoader());
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("courses", card.getCourses());
context.startActivity(intent);
```

And when I call the **startActivity** I get the following error:

```
E/Parcel﹕ Class not found when unmarshalling: pt.tecnico.fenixmobile.person.CurriculumCourseCard, e: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: pt.tecnico.fenixmobile.person.CurriculumCourseCard
```

**CurriculumCourseCard** implements the **Parcelable** interface. Here's is the implementation:

```
public class CurriculumCourseCard implements Serializable, Parcelable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 765578940083L;
private String courseName;
private String finalGrade;
private String ects;

public CurriculumCourseCard(Parcel in) {
    this.courseName = in.readString();
    this.finalGrade = in.readString();
    this.ects = in.readString();
}

public String getCourseName() {
    return courseName;
}

public String getFinalGrade() {
    return finalGrade;
}

public String getEcts() {
    return ects;
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    parcel.writeString(this.courseName);
    parcel.writeString(this.finalGrade);
    parcel.writeString(this.ects);
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public CurriculumCourseCard createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new CurriculumCourseCard(in);
    }

    public CurriculumCourseCard[] newArray(int size) {
        return new CurriculumCourseCard[size];
    }
};}
```

And this is how I'm getting the list in the new activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
intent.setExtrasClassLoader(CurriculumCourseCard.class.getClassLoader());
ArrayList<CurriculumCourseCard> courses = intent.getParcelableArrayListExtra("courses");
```

In the new `activity` I see as much items as there are in the list, but no content at all. And the only error is the one described before.

Hope you can help me.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15005615/class-not-found-when-unmarshalling-when-passing-parcelable-through-messenger-to

Comment: post the rest of `onCreate()` in `CurriculumCorsesActivity`

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your answers. I've solve the problem by sending a bundle object which contains my parcelable.