# BadParcelableException: unmarshalling: com.android.mail.providers.Account

Tags: android, email, android-intent, classloader

I know that this a looks duplicate thread. But, I could not find the solution for this..

I have a application in which I try to a Intent filter for

```
android.intent.action.VIEW
```

When I touch on a email-id, it opens my activity. But throws `BadParcelableException: unmarshalling: com.android.mail.providers.Account`.

I tried setting the ClassLoader to the bundle. But did not work.

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras() ;
bundle.setClassLoader(getClassLoader()) ;
```

As per the other posts they just say `getClass().getClassLoader()`.

My Question is what should be the value for class loader?

Kindly, point me to the right direction.

Thanks in advance.

**Stack trace:**

```
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.android.mail.providers.Account
    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2077)
    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1965)
    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2226)
    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:223)
    at android.os.Bundle.getBoolean(Bundle.java:802)
    at android.content.Intent.getBooleanExtra(Intent.java:4354)
    at com.example.activities.HandleView.access$0(SourceFile:225)
    at com.example.activities.HandleView$1.handleMessage(SourceFile:1010)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5297)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**Intent Filter:**

```
<activity
            android:name=".activities.HandleView"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO" />

                <data android:scheme="mailto" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />

                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND_MULTIPLE" />

                <data android:mimeType="*/*" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: "My Question is what should be the value for class loader? " -- there is none. That class is part of another application. This suggests a bug in Android somewhere. Please post your entire stack trace, plus the `<intent-filter>` your activity is matching.

Comment: have you check this so# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393751/badparcelableexception-classnotfoundexception-when-unmarshalling

Comment: @Yup, yes I have seen it.. Here the user has his Parcelable class. But in my case, I am not sure which class will parcel it.. I just need to know what should be the class loader to be set. Thanks