# Marshalling and unmarshalling a List<List<T>> with Android's Parcel

Tags: android, marshalling, unmarshalling, parcelable

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` when trying to unmarshall a `List<List<LatLng>` in a custom class which implements `Parcelable`. How do I get rid of this exception?

Here's my class:

```
public class Country implements Parcelable {

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Country> CREATOR = new Creator<Country>() {

        @Override
        public Country[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Country[size];
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        public Country createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            Country country = new Country();
            country.name = source.readString();
            country.borders = source.readArrayList(Country.class
                    .getClassLoader());
            return country;
        }
    };

    public String name;

    public List<List<LatLng>> borders;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeList(borders);
    }

}
```

And here's my logcat:

```
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{codeguru.worldtour/codeguru.worldtour.MainActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: codeguru.worldtour.Country
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1654)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1670)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2844)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3695)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991): Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: codeguru.worldtour.Country
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1958)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1846)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2092)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1536)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1867)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Bundle.getBundle(Bundle.java:1078)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at ekg.a(SourceFile:74)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at maps.e.al.a(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at maps.e.bj.a(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at eir.onTransact(SourceFile:66)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:279)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.IMapViewDelegate$a$a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$3.b(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a$1.a(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.eb(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView$b.a(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.a(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.a.onCreate(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(Unknown Source)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at codeguru.worldtour.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:63)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1618)
03-08 22:09:43.749: E/AndroidRuntime(16991):    ... 12 more
```

**Marshalling:**

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putParcelableArrayList(COUNTRIES_KEY, countries);
    savedInstanceState.putInt(COUNTRIES_INDEX_KEY, countryIndex);
}
```

**Unmarshalling (in `onCreate()`):**

```
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        countryIndex = savedInstanceState.getInt(COUNTRIES_INDEX_KEY, -1);
        countries = savedInstanceState
                .getParcelableArrayList(COUNTRIES_KEY);
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the code that initiates the marshalling/unmarshalling sequence, i.e. codeguru.worldtour.MainActivity.onCreate line 63 ? It looks like an IPC problem.

Comment: @Snicolas Your wish is my command

Comment: Can you edit your code to include your `LatLng` class?

Comment: @Trust `LatLng` is from the Google Maps v2 API

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

Make sure `LatLng` implements `Parcelable`. Otherwise the activity will not know how to marshall and unmarshall it when it has to marshall/unmarshall `Country` (which is why you may be getting the error: `The inferred type List<LatLng> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Parcelable>`.

This should work - create a class to extend `ArrayList<LatLng>`. The idea is to use the `CREATOR` of `ParcelableArrayList` (the class below) to create your list. It will only work if you instantiate your list as an `ArrayList` (as another answer mentioned you should do).

```
public class ParcelableArrayList extends ArrayList<LatLng> implements 
    Parcelable {

public ParcelableArrayList(){
    super();
}

protected ParcelableArrayList(Parcel in) {
    in.readList(this, LatLng.class.getClassLoader());
}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(this);
}   

public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableArrayList> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParcelableArrayList>() {
    public ParcelableArrayList createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new ParcelableArrayList(in);
    }

    public ParcelableArrayList[] newArray(int size) {
        return new ParcelableArrayList[size];
    }
};
}
```

Now, in your `Country` class:

```
public class Country implements Parcelable {

public static final Parcelable.Creator<Country> CREATOR = new Creator<Country>() {

    @Override
    public Country[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Country[size];
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Country createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new Country(in);
    }
};

public String name;
public List<ParcelableArrayList> borders;

public Country(Parcel source) {

    country.name = source.readString();

    country.borders = new ArrayList<ParcelableArrayList()>();
    country.borders = source.readTypedList(ParcelableArrayList.CREATOR);

}

@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeList(borders);
}

}
```

Edit 2:

Okay, instead of reading with `Parcel#readTypedList()` , try using `Parcel#readList()` instead. So replace:

```
    country.borders = new ArrayList<ParcelableArrayList()>();
    country.borders = source.readTypedList(ParcelableArrayList.CREATOR);
```

with

```
    country.borders = new ArrayList<ParcelableArrayList()>();
    country.borders = source.readList(country.borders, ParcelableArrayList.class.getClassLoader());
```

I tested this in an app of my own and it worked with no compile time or runtime errors (as far as I can see).

Comment: I have no control over the `LatLng` class. It is from the Google Maps API.

Comment: From here (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLng) I see that `LatLng` already implements `Parcelable`, so you're good to go. Have you tried using the above approach?

Comment: "The inferred type List<LatLng> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Parcelable>." is caused by the fact that `T` is referring to a `List<LatLng>` (i.e. I am trying to marshall a list of lists.)

Comment: See my edit. `readList` instead of `readTypedList` should be able to read the `List of ParcelableArrayList`s without error as far as I know .

Answer (score 0):

Following the thread here and all comments on answers : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4915219/693752

It may be interesting to :

- declare borders as an array list (not a list)
- use `parcel.writeTypedList(List)` to write the list of borders
- use `parcel.createTypedArrayList` to read it from the parcel. It looks like `readArrayList`is difficult to handle.

Comment: `writeTypedList()` gives a compiler error: Bound mismatch: The generic method writeTypedList(List<T>) of type Parcel is not applicable for the arguments (List<List<LatLng>>). The inferred type List<LatLng> is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter <T extends Parcelable>

Comment: Can't you replace your list of list with a parcelabel data structure ?

Answer (score 0):

Add a constructor that takes parcel as argument and Add a Creator to your class.

```
public Country(Parcel source) {
    country.name = source.readString();
    country.borders = source.readArrayList(Country.class
                .getClassLoader());
}

@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
    public Country createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        return new Country(in);
    }

    public Country[] newArray(int size) {
        return new Country[size];
    }
};
```

Comment: This works when I send a class inside an intent.  I haven't tried this with arrays or the readArrayList.

Comment: Does this differ in a fundamental way from the code posted in my OP?

Comment: It doesn't as far as I can see; for readability however, I'd write a separate constructor (seems to be the convention followed).

Comment: I know from step debugging the constructor with parcel is used in the unmarshaling.

Comment: @danny117 AFAICT, the `Country(Parcel)` constructor is used for unmarshalling because you call it explicitly from `createFromParcel()`.

Comment: I was talking about the original question code didn't have the Country(Parcel) constructor or the the Creator

Answer (score 0):

I tackled this with breaking `List<List<LatLng>>` into `List<CustomClass>`
where `CustomClass extends ArrayList<LatLng>>`

here is my code of CustomClass

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Lister extends ArrayList<AlertEvaluation> implements Parcelable {

    protected Lister(Parcel in) {
        this.addAll(in.readArrayList(AlertEvaluation.class.getClassLoader()));
    }

    public static final Creator<Lister> CREATOR = new Creator<Lister>() {
        @Override
        public Lister createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Lister(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Lister[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Lister[size];
        }
    };

    @Override public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeList(this);
    }
}
```