# android phone app,browser app,map app crashes when I am using intent to start them from my app

Tags: android, android-intent

I am starting different apps like phone app, browser app, maps app from my app something like this

```
 String url = "http://www." + textView.getText().toString();
            Log.d(TAG,url);
            Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            mContext.startActivity(i);
```

At first they worked perfectly but now every app crashes like
"unfortunetly chorme stopped working" or "unfortunetly dialer has stopped working" etc. I hope some one knows why its happening. Thanks in advance.

This is my logcat

```
05-08 19:12:28.720  10227-10227/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.google.android.apps.maps, PID: 10227
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.google.android.apps.maps/com.google.android.maps.MapsActivity}: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.example.krishnateja.bigapplesearch.models.MTAMainScreenModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.example.krishnateja.bigapplesearch.models.MTAMainScreenModel
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableCreator(Parcel.java:2289)
        at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:2239)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2146)
        at android.os.Parcel.readListInternal(Parcel.java:2520)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayList(Parcel.java:1836)
        at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:2167)
        at android.os.Parcel.readArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:2479)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.unparcel(BaseBundle.java:221)
        at android.os.BaseBundle.getIntArray(BaseBundle.java:1164)
        at android.content.Intent.getIntArrayExtra(Intent.java:5004)
        at com.google.android.apps.gmm.m.l.a(PG:1061)
        at com.google.android.apps.gmm.m.w.a(PG:2241)
        at com.google.android.apps.gmm.base.activities.a.onNewIntent(PG:953)
        at com.google.android.apps.gmm.base.activities.a.onCreate(PG:641)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
        at
```

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996294/problem-unmarshalling-parcelables/3806769#3806769 . Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @user3653796 but I couldnt relate my problem with that solution

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the class not found is I am overiding start activity for some other intent but I did not have an if condition saying add extra to the particular intent. A silly mistake.